# terminal showing ": " sign and then i can't command anything . how to remove this or command again

Tags: git, terminal, command

when I command --> git log --oneline
then show some log and lastly show this sign ":"
after showing this sign I can't command any code

please help me to solve this 
[git command in terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqtr4.png)

Comment: It sounds like you're in your pager (almost certainly `less`). Press `q` to exit. You can also suspend most commands with `ctrl`+`Z`, and then use your shell's job control mechanisms to identify and kill the process. [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Basics.html) is the documentation for that in Bash.

Answer (score 0):

You can start playing with [LESS options](https://linux.die.net/man/1/less) to avoid the `:`

Or simply replace the pager used by Git in order to not interrupt the display page after page:

```
git config --global core.pager cat
```

I prefer:

```
git config --global --replace-all core.pager "less -JMQRiFXE"
```

The final "E" is important:

```
-E or --QUIT-AT-EOF
    Causes less to automatically exit the first time it reaches end-of-file.
```

If the output of your Git command does not fill out the full shell height (one "page"), then the GIt command would end immediately, without you having to type '<kbd>q</kbd>' to exit the pager.